When I translate during the dark mode, background property disappears from card-content in Angular
`In my angular project, I did a toggle-switch via <mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle> for switching between dark mode and light mode. However, when I translate my application during dark mode the card-contents background property disappears. The gif explaining my issue is here:
(https://i.sstatic.net/fXN99.gif)
I tried to add my dark-theme mode via functions in my application. However background object disappears in card-content when I translate in dark mode.
Here is my home-component.html where I have this issue in:
<section>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="products-title">New Arrivals</h1>
    <div class="products-list">
      <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="card">
        <div class="card-content" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': isDarkTheme ? '#5eda5e' : '#3b5b2d'}">
          <img class="product-image" [src]="product.imgSrc" [alt]="">
          <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name | translate}}</h2>
          <p class="product-description">{{ product.description | translate}}</p>
          <p class="product-price">{{ product.price | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.2-2' }}</p>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

And this is my home-component.ts:
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Product } from '../product.model';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./home.component.css'\]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
products: Product\[\] = \[\];
isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
langChangeSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private productService: ProductService, public translate: TranslateService) {
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
this.translate.use('en');
translate.addLangs(\['en', 'tr'\]);

    this.langChangeSubscription = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.updateProducts();
    });

}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
console.log('Dark mode:', this.isDarkTheme);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.isDarkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === "Dark";
this.updateProducts();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
this.langChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

switchLanguage(lang: string) {
this.translate.use(lang);
}

ChangeLang(event: any) {
const lang = event.target.value;
this.switchLanguage(lang);
}

private updateProducts() {
this.products = this.productService.getProducts();
}
}

This is my header-component.html:
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-bar" [ngClass]="{'dark-theme-mode':isDarkTheme}">
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="'/home'">
                <img class="logo" src="assets/img/goodfellas-logo.png">
            </a>
        </li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <span class="menu" [ngClass]="{'dark-theme-mode':isDarkTheme}">
            <li>
                <a class="fruit-link" [routerLink]="'/fruits'"> <img class="fruit-icon" src="assets/img/fruit.png">{{ 'fruit_title' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="vegetable-link" [routerLink]="'/vegetables'"><img class="vegetable-icon" src="assets/img/vegetable.png">{{ 'vegetable_title' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="'/drinks'"><img class="drink-icon" src="assets/img/water.png">{{ 'drink_title' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="'/login'"><img class="login-icon" src="assets/img/login.png">{{ 'login' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="'/not-registered-sign-in'"><img class="register-icon" src="assets/img/register.png">{{ 'register' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="shopping-cart" src="assets/img/shopping-cart.png">
            </li>
            <li>
                <form class="languages">
                    <label for="language">Language/Dil:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" (change)="ChangeLang($event)" id="languageSelect" [ngClass]="{'dark-theme-mode':isDarkTheme}">
                       <option [value]="'en'" [selected]="translate.currentLang === 'en'">English</option>
                       <option [value]="'tr'" [selected]="translate.currentLang === 'tr'">Türkçe</option>
                    </select>
                 </form>                                         
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- part for dark mode/light mode switch button -->
                <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isDarkTheme" labelPosition="before" (change)="storeThemeSelection()">
                    <img [src]="isDarkTheme ? dark_mode : light_mode" alt="Theme Image">
                </mat-slide-toggle>                                        
            </li>
            <label for="check" class="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
        </span>
        <label for="check" class="open-menu">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
    </ul>
</nav>

also this is my header-component.ts:
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrl: './header.component.css'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
isDarkTheme: boolean = false;

// Initialize dark_mode and light_mode with translation keys
dark_mode: string = 'assets/img/crescent-moon.png';
light_mode: string = 'assets/img/sunny.png';

constructor(public translate: TranslateService, private renderer: Renderer2) {
// Set default language
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
// Set initial language if needed
this.translate.use('en');
translate.addLangs(\['en', 'tr'\]);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.isDarkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === "Dark";
this.translate.get('assets/img/crescent-moon.png').subscribe((res: string) =\> {
this.dark_mode = res;
});
this.translate.get('assets/img/sunny.png').subscribe((res: string) =\> {
this.light_mode = res;
});
this.setBodyBackground();
this.productText();
}

switchLanguage(lang: string) {
this.translate.use(lang);
}

ChangeLang(event: any) {
const lang = event.target.value;
this.switchLanguage(lang);
localStorage.setItem('theme', this.isDarkTheme ? 'Dark' : 'Light');
this.languageBackground();
}

storeThemeSelection() {
localStorage.setItem('theme', this.isDarkTheme ? 'Dark' : 'Light');
this.setBodyBackground();
this.productText();
this.footerBackground();
this.cardBackground();
}

private setBodyBackground() {
const backgroundColor = this.isDarkTheme ? '#3b5b2d' : '#5eda5e';
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', backgroundColor);
}

private productText() {
const color = this.isDarkTheme ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'color', color);
}

private footerBackground() {
const footerBackgroundColor = this.isDarkTheme ? '#4d4d4d' : '#ffffff';
this.renderer.setStyle(document.querySelector('.footer'), 'background-color', footerBackgroundColor);
}

private languageBackground() {
const color = this.isDarkTheme ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'color', color);
}

private cardBackground() {
const backgroundColor = this.isDarkTheme ? '#5eda5e' : '#3b5b2d';
const cardContents = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content');
cardContents.forEach(cardContent =\> {
this.renderer.setStyle(cardContent, 'background-color', backgroundColor);
});
}  
}

By the way I use ngx app for translation and please forgive me if my question is in bad format since its my first question.`

If you seek an easy go solution here is your answer:

Let's take a look when we change its value in the code:

I have definitely seen that you also access to those cards' DOM through renderer api and update their styles inside header.component.ts. However, here is the key point: When you call updateProducts inside home.component.ts, it destroys all the items and recreate them in the DOM. That's the reason why changing style in header.component.ts won't mean anything in that case. They'll be destroyed and recreated. After re-creation it'll look the value of isDarkTheme inside home.component.ts and you actually didn't update that value. Therefore the basic solution is adding this one line of code:
this.langChangeSubscription = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      // Update isDarkTheme value here!
      this.isDarkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === "Dark";
      this.updateProducts();
});


Thank you so much for your explanation. I forgot about that detail. You solved my question.
